# Follow mode for describe-function/describe-variable

Tags: help, follow-mode

When learning elisp by reading source code (on a large screen) it would be nice to have something like a "follow mode", which automaticaly displays the output of `describe-variable` or `describe-function` on a seperate dedicated window. So as you move around the cursor you will see in another window always the description of the function or variable at point without pressing any additional key.

Is there any package which does this already?

Comment: In Emacs Lisp buffers, Eldoc shows variable docstring and function signature in the echo area out of the box. It is also possible to show the function's docstring if you advice `elisp-get-fnsym-args-string`.

Comment: The Emacs wiki has [an example](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc#toc6) of how to write the advice that @xuchunyang is suggesting.